# How do I get the operator module's sorted function to store data so that I can append a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file-io

I am trying to store the data from datalist.csv in the variable "sort" so that I can append the data to a file, however, it is returning a null field.

a sample file for datalist.csv is

```
W_A11, 2000-02, Moving average, 59.66666667, 50.92582302, 68.40751031, Injuries, Number, Assault, Validated, Whole pop, All ages, Fatal,
W_A12, 2000-02, Moving average, 1.543343121, 1.317063238, 1.769623003, Per 100,000 people, Age-standardised rate, Assault, Validated, Whole pop, All ages, Fatal,
W_F11B, 2000-02, Moving average, 64.33333333, 55.25710337, 73.40956329, Injuries, Number, Falls, Validated, Whole pop, 0-74 years, Fatal
```

I am unsure what to try.

```
infile = open("datalist.csv", "r")
    next(infile)
    for line in infile:
        line.strip("'")
        line.strip('"')
    csvfile = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    csvfile = list(csvfile)
    sort = sorted(csvfile, key= operator.itemgetter(6))
for line in sort:
   print(line)
```

I expect sort to store the data from datalist.csv and for the print statement to return the csv but organized by the sixth index value. It returns a null field instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop:

```
for line in infile:
    line.strip("'")
    line.strip('"')
```

consumes `infile` completely (and does nothing to the lines; `strip` doesn't mutate the data in place, and it's probably not doing what you think it's doing anyway, it only strips leading and trailing quotes from the whole line, not per field).

Thus, when you reach:

```
csvfile = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
```

the `reader` has nothing to read.

Get rid of the loop, leaving (after a few more cleanups like using `with` statements and passing `newline=''` to meet `csv` module requirements):

```
with open("datalist.csv", newline='') as infile:
    csvfile = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    next(csvfile)
    sort = sorted(csvfile, key=operator.itemgetter(6))
for line in sort:
    print(line)
```

and it should work.

Comment: This fully resolved my problem! Thanks a lot ShadowRanger.